# Setting up Akka cluster for Lagom application in production mode

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, production, lagom

I'm trying to run a Lagom service in production mode in an Akka cluster, which is configured via `Akka Cluster Bootstrap` as described in https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/scala/Cluster.html. (I was able to run the app by specifying seed nodes manually). However, I could not manage to start the service. I have the following setup:

```
application.conf (only the cluster related configs)
akka.management.cluster.bootstrap {
  # example using kubernetes-api
  contact-point-discovery {
    discovery-method = akka.discovery
#    discovery-method = config
    service-name = "lagom-scala"
    required-contact-point-nr = 0
  }
}
```

An application loader, loading the `AkkaDiscoveryComponents` in the production mode as described here (https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/scala/AkkaDiscoveryIntegration.html):

```
class LagomscalaLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new LagomscalaApplication(context) with AkkaDiscoveryComponents

  override def loadDevMode(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new LagomscalaApplication(context) with LagomDevModeComponents

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[LagomscalaService])
}
```

I get the following logs when `required-contact-point-nr` is set to `0`:

```
2019-10-28T23:48:54.867Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-26, akkaTimestamp=23:48:54.867UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application] - Looking up [Lookup(lagom-scala,None,Some(tcp))]
2019-10-28T23:48:54.886Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22, akkaTimestamp=23:48:54.886UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(lagom-scala,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2019-10-28T23:48:55.957Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16, akkaTimestamp=23:48:55.957UTC, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Exceeded stable margins without locating seed-nodes, however this node 192.168.0.34:8558 is NOT the lowest address out of the discovered endpoints in this deployment, thus NOT joining self. Expecting node [] (out of []) to perform the self-join and initiate the cluster.
```

When I set `required-contact-point-nr` to `2` (default), I get the following logs:

```
2019-10-29T00:15:57.846Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23, akkaTimestamp=00:15:57.846UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application] - Looking up [Lookup(lagom-scala,None,Some(tcp))]
2019-10-29T00:15:57.865Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=00:15:57.865UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(lagom-scala,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2019-10-29T00:15:58.299Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3, akkaTimestamp=00:15:58.299UTC, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
2019-10-29T00:15:58.599Z [warn] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=00:15:58.597UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/sharding/kafkaProducer-greetings, sourceActorSystem=application] - kafkaProducer-greetings: No coordinator found to register. Probably, no seed-nodes configured and manual cluster join not performed? Total [1] buffered messages.
```

I use `Akka 2.5.25` and default configurations except the ones I specified above. E.g. I see the following logs that might be of relevance after running the service:

```
2019-10-29T00:15:44.987Z [info] akka.remote.Remoting [sourceThread=main, akkaTimestamp=00:15:44.987UTC, akkaSource=akka.remote.Remoting, sourceActorSystem=application] - Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552]
2019-10-29T00:15:45.276Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application) [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=00:15:45.275UTC] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html#joining-to-seed-nodes
2019-10-29T00:15:46.411Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap [sourceThread=main, akkaTimestamp=00:15:46.411UTC, akkaSource=ClusterBootstrap(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Using self contact point address: http://192.168.0.34:8558
2019-10-29T00:15:48.164Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-24, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=00:15:48.163UTC] - Bound Akka Management (HTTP) endpoint to: 192.168.0.34:8558
2019-10-29T00:15:48.286Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-24, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.34:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=00:15:48.285UTC] - Locating service members. Using discovery [akka.discovery.aggregate.AggregateServiceDiscovery], join decider [akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider]
2019-10-29T00:15:48.772Z [info] play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer [] - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

So, I think there is a mismatch between the ports but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks odd since there no any joining nodes being discovered but the `192.168.0.34:8558` eventually turns out to be NOT the lowest address. So your Akka Bootstrap walks through the nodes and tries to figure out whether any of their contact points have any seed-nodes. Than it should join self and starts acting as a seed-node but it doesn't happen. In the second case it discovers no any contact ponts at all. Can you please provide more info on how do you starting the app?

Comment: Please also share your `akka.management.http.hostname`

Comment: I use `sbt dist` to create the package and run the generated script like:`./lagom-scala-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/lagom-scala-impl -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeasdf`. I use the default for `akka.management.http.hostname`. I guess it is `localhost` by default.

For convenience, I created a zip package of my project structure, which is available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngnx2h0b9jx7sik/lagom-scala.zip?dl=0 . I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I also tried to define `lagom.akka.discovery.service-name-mappings` like 
`service-name-mappings {
    lagom-scala {
        lookup = "lagom-scala" (or "_http._tcp.lagom-scala")
        scheme = http
    }
  }` but those didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was a missing DNS server in the local settings and the fact that Lagom itself does not provide a DNS server
as stated by @tim-moore at [Lightbend forum](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/failed-to-set-up-a-cluster-using-akka-cluster-bootstrap-without-specifying-seed-nodes/5324/4).

Comment: Have you tried to deploy your service to OpenShift / K8s?

Comment: No I have not. I'm trying to deploy it locally by simply running the generated jar by something like: `./lagom-scala-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/lagom-scala-impl -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeasdf.`